Reusing constants in tests vs "magic" values
I'm writing tests to check if validation rules are working for my CRUD app. I have constants defining stuff like max length of each String field. I'm unsure if within tests I should create test data by using those constants, or input invalid values manually instead.
A simplified example looks like this:
class CreateCustomerDTO{
   public static int NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT = 50;

   @Size(max = NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT)
   private String firstName;

   @Size(max = NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT)
   private String lastName;
}

Test option #1:
@Test
void shouldThrow400WhenInvalidCustomer() {
    //create customer ...

    customerDto.setLastName("x".repeat(NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT + 1));
    postRequest(customerDto, status().is4xxClientError());

Test option #2:
@Test
void shouldThrow400WhenInvalidCustomer() {
    //create customer ...

    customerDto.setLastName("x".repeat(51));
    //..or maybe even this: 
    customerDto.setLastName("veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeryLongNameThatExceedsTheLimit); //51 characters

    postRequest(customerDto, status().is4xxClientError());

Option #1 does not test the actual number, but rather the behaviour("if a field exceeds the size limit, whatever that limit might be, should throw 400"). You don't need to manually change all the test values whenever a modification to the validation rules is requested.
Option #2 tests the behaviour but also the actual number. If there is a change request to set the limit to 500, and the developer accidentally sets it to 50, tests will detect something is wrong and make the dev double check his typo (unless you make the same typo both in implementation and in test data creation - very unlikely).
However, everytime a change is requested you have to update all test data to be consistent with the business rule.

First, it is never a good idea to distribute knowledge about the correct value for something like NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT over too many places in the code. Ideally, there should be a single source of truth. Imagine you have 20 tests which all depend on this value, do you really want to change them all when when the requirement for the maximum name length will be changed?
Of course, imagine there are two persons involved, one writing the tests and another one writing the production code. Now the test author wants to verify the production code author used the correct value, without looking into their code. Then - hypothetically - introducing a constant like NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT_REQUIRED=50 into the tests (or some of them) could be an option. That can keep the test code DRY and allows to distinguish beetween tests for the behaviour (using NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT) and tests for the actual number (using NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT_REQUIRED). As mentioned by @BartVanIngenSchenau, you will probably end uo with a single test
 assert(NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT == NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT_REQUIRED)

and if that is the only place where NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT_REQUIRED is used, replacing the constant by the literal, like assert(NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT == 50) is completely sufficient.
In reality, however, I think it is often much more effective to verify the correctness of NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT by a code review. That approach will suit you most in case the test code author and the prod code author are the same person.

To add: If it is really critical that this constant has a particular value, add 1 test that verifies the value of the constant (assert(NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT == 50)), but write all other tests referring to NAME_LENGTH_LIMIT.

@BartvanIngenSchenau thanks, your tip is really simple and seems like the most reasonable solution.

@Domin0, use it only if the reason for having this particular value is more involved than "we needed a value and this seemed to be large enough". If any (large enough) number could have worked, there is no point in testing for the actual value.

I would really question the value of these "is the correct error thrown in X circumstance" tests.
Presumably you are not hand coding the error code and message for every error. You have some framework which throws 400 errors for invalid parameters and that framework has its own unit tests.
You need to test that your application can handle a name of X length. Maybe you need to test that it won't accept names longer than Y, but testing for a specific error only leads to thousands of brittle, pointless tests.

Using constants in test rather than magic values improves readability, maintainability, consistency, and overall code quality. its makes the intent behind the code clearer and ensure that changes can be manage in a single location, reducing the chance of introducing error
